# How to call a user defined function in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, user-defined-functions, hiveql

I want to write a hive query that depends on paramaters passed into a script. These parameters might require me to select from an unknown number of columns.
What I want to do is have one of the arguments passed to the script be a string containing column names, delimited by some regex, probably a comma.
I've been pulling my hair out trying to convert a simple string into an array using the split UDF and use the resultant array in a query.
Basically, given 
    A="Foo,Bar"
I want to get 
    B=[Foo, Bar]
Then be able to do a query such as SELECT B[0] from tablename;
A clarification: I'm trying to split a variable I've passed in.

EDIT:
I've realized ideally I wouldn't be doing this- is there any way to construct a hive query and pass it in?

EDIT2:
Using the -e flag. Not really the best practice, but I can't see another way to do this. Maybe utilizing pig would have been a better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just pass list of columns that you want to select. For example this script has one variable COLUMNS

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3://dummy/dummy/'
select ${COLUMNS} from table;
```

When running this using CLI just pass list of columns you want to select like this

```
$> hive -f <path to script> -d COLUMNS=col1,col2,col3
```

HTH,
Dino

Comment: That makes sense - looks like I have some refactoring to do! Thanks.